# Disable eslint for previous commits

Tags: javascript, eslint, prettier, eslintrc, eslint-config-airbnb

I am new to eslint and prettier. I am trying to set these up and wondering if there is a way to disable eslint and prettier for previous commits in the repo and run it only on the new code or new checkins? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe can try this https://github.com/grvcoelho/lint-diff.

And check:

> ..., it cannot be used to enforce the styleguide on a Continuous Integration service like Travis, because the changes are already commited.

Comment: Thanks, I installed `lint-diff` and I can see the lint-diff command in my 
 `./node_modules/.bin/lint-diff` yet when I try to run only `lint-diff` it says command not found. Any idea why it can't pick it when it is already in `.bin` directory? thank you in advance.